# How to get return from event loop functions

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am rookie at async.
So, my goal is to get array of responses from event loop. I don't actually understand where this `return html_text` goes after all.
Can you, please, correct my code or offer an alternative solution?

```
urls = [https://www.google.com, https://www.youtube.com/]

async def r_get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
            resp.encoding = 'utf-8'
            html_text = await resp.text())
    return html_text


urls = [asyncio.ensure_future(r_get(url)) for url in urls_with_id]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*urls))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run_until_complete` returns the value returned by the coroutine it runs. In turn, `gather` returns a tuple of the return values of the coroutines it awaits to completion. When the two are used together, `run_until_complete(gather(a(), b(), c()))` will return a tuple of values returned by `a()`, `b()`, and `c()` respectively.

In your case, just pick up the results by assigning them to a variables:

```
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*urls))
# ...use results...
```